# global name 'RomanNumeralConverter' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm trying to write a unittest, but always get error on globalname not define.

my code in test_TestCase.py

```
import unittest


class RomanNumeralConverterTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_parsing_millenia(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter("M")  # type: RomanNumeralConverter
        self.assertEquals(1000, value.convert_to_decimal)

    def test_parsing_century(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter("C")
        self.assertEquals(100, value.convert_to_decimal())

    def test_parsing_half_century(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter("L")
        self.assertEquals(50, value.convert_to_decimal())

    def test_parsing_decade(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter("X")
        self.assertEquals(10, value.convert_to_decimal())

    def test_parsing_half_decade(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter("V")
        self.assertEquals(5, value.convert_to_decimal())

    def test_parsing_parsing_one(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter("I")
        self.assertEquals(1, value.convert_to_decimal())

    def test_empty_roman_numeral(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter(" ")
        self.assertTrue(value.convert_to_decimal() == 0)
        self.assertFalse(value.convert_to_decimal() > 0)

    def test_no_roman_numeral(self):
        value = RomanNumeralConverter(None)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, value.convert_to_decimal)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

code in recipe1.py

```
class RomanNumeralConverter(object):

    def __init__(self, roman_numeral):
        self.roman_numeral = roman_numeral
        self.digit_map = {"M": 1000, "D": 500, "C": 100, "L": 50, "X": 10, "V": 5, "I": 1}

    @property
    def convert_to_decimal(self):
        val = 0  # type: int
        for char in self.roman_numeral:
            val += self.digit_map[char]
        return val
```

NameError: global name 'RomanNumeralConverter' is not defined

---

Ran 8 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=8)

Answer (score 0):

In your unittest.py, looks like u have missed importing the class you have defined in the other file..

Comment: how to import class from recipe1.py?

Comment: Assuming both your files are in same folder, and also that folder contains a file by name __init__.py just import using import RomanNumeralConverter from recipe1

Comment: i dont have a init.py in my folder, only recipe.py and test_TestCase.py. should i create one and what inside init.py should contain?

sorry i'm a beginner for this

Comment: That's fine.. Just add an empty file and name it __init__.py.. for python 2.x version this file is import to that the folder is actually a python package.. it's implicit in 3.x python version.. Note: make sure init.py has 2 underscores before and after init.. when I type it here, it's converting the text to hold instead of underscores..